# Calling init() in view the best way to pull firebase data?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I have a `SearchView()`

```
struct SearchView: View {

@ObservedObject var searchViewModel = SearchViewModel()
init() {
    searchViewModel.LoadAllUsers()
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(searchViewModel.allUsers, id: \.uid) { user in
                    ......
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my `SearchViewModel` I have a function which gets all users from firebase and stores them in and `@Published` `allUsers` array:

```
@Published var allUsers: [User] = []

func LoadAllUsers() {
     Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).getDocument{(snapshot, error) in
    ....
}
```

Every time I click on the `SearchView()` Its going and running the function and calling firebase and getting the data. Is this the best way? this could in the long run increase the costs on firebase? Is there not a way to call this function every time the app loads rather than every time the `SearchView()` loads?

**UPDATE**

```
var window: UIWindow?
var searchViewModel = SearchViewModel()

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

    // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
    //let contentView = ContentView()
    
    searchViewModel.LoadAllUsers()
    
    // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: InitialView().environmentObject(SessionStore()).environmentObject(searchViewModel))
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

In my SearchViewModel an issue is occurring due to the following:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Due to the following:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
```

Answer (score 1):

In such case it would be appropriate to make it in `SceneDelegate` and inject into hierarchy as environment object, like

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    var searchViewModel = SearchViewModel() // create

    ...
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

       searchViewModel.LoadAllUsers()        // << preload !!
       ...
       let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(searchViewModel) // << inject !!
```

and

```
struct SearchView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var searchViewModel: SearchViewModel    // << use !!
    // nothing in init
```

Comment: I made the following changes, which is still causing me an issue due to when Its being called? I have updated my question. Thanks